# How to make both hover and click popup work?

Tags: leaflet, popup

I am pretty new to all of this.

I want to have a hover/mouseover AND click popup work on my geojson layer.
Here is the code so far, but I don't know where to include the hover without messing up the click popup. The hover should show the content of a text field and highlight the circle marker.

```js
$.getJSON('http://soundgoods.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?format=GeoJSON&q=SELECT * FROM soundgoods_mixtape_map_1', function(data) {
var geojsonMarkerOptions = {
    radius: 8,
    fillColor: "#FFCC00",
    color: "#323232",
    weight: 2,
    opacity: 0.5,
    fillOpacity: 0.4
    };

var geojson = L.geoJson(data, {

    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        var popupOptions = {maxWidth: 500};
        var popupContent = '<a target="_blank" class="popup" href="' +
                feature.properties.post + '">' +
                feature.properties.soundcloud +
                '<h3>' + "Post & tracklist" + '</h3>' + '</a>';
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions).bindPopup(popupContent,popupOptions,{

        });

    }

});
markers.addLayer(geojson);

// CONSTRUCT THE MAP
var map = L.map('map').setView([0,0],3);
baseLayer.addTo(map);
markers.addTo(map);
```

Comment: Please can you explain what you want to happen on mouseover?

Comment: Sorry, edited the question. thanks for formatting.

Answer (score 5):

As @ghybs said, attach events to the circle markers themselves inside `pointToLayer`, like so:

```js
pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    var popupOptions = {maxWidth: 500};
    var popupContent = '<a target="_blank" class="popup" href="' +
            feature.properties.post + '">' +
            feature.properties.soundcloud +
            '<h3>' + "Post & tracklist" + '</h3>' + '</a>';
    var circle = L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions).bindPopup(popupContent,popupOptions);

    // Highlight the marker on hover
    circle.on('mouseover', function(){
        circle.setStyle({ color: 'red' });
    });

    // Un-highlight the marker on hover out
    circle.on('mouseout', function(){
        circle.setStyle(geojsonMarkerOptions);
    });

    // Open the popup on click. Actually optional, as popup automatically adds a click listener.
    circle.bindPopup(popupContent, popupOptions);
    circle.on('click', function(){
        circle.openPopup(latlng);
    });

    return circle;
}
```

Comment: Hi Ivan,many thanks for the reply, but when I add your code nothing changes, no highlighting on mouse over...

Comment: Ivan's code should work, once corrected for the minor code mistake. Op's initial version: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/202/ With Ivan's code: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/203/

Comment: OK, cool, the highlighting works, but not the hover popup... Will check the solution below. Many thanks so far!

Comment: @IvanSanchez A+. Question: why do you bind twice the circle? you have 2 bindPopup you can use only once no?

Comment: @adhg You're right, I mistakenly wrote code that calls `bindPopup()` twice, and the second could be simplified away. Fortunately, several calls to `bindPopup()` have no ill effect, since the current implementation will update the contents of a bound popup if there's a popup already bound.

Comment: @IvanSanchez great; thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

As for showing some text when the mouse is over a vector shape (GeoJSON feature), you would be interested in [Leaflet.label plugin](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.label) ([demo](http://leaflet.github.com/Leaflet.label/)).

> Leaflet.label is plugin for adding labels to markers & shapes on leaflet powered maps.

Regarding highlighting / changing the style of the circle marker, you should use `"mouseover"` and `"mouseout"` events on each feature of your GeoJSON layer group, as shown in that Leaflet tutorial: Interactive Choropleth Map, [section "Adding Interaction"](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html#adding-interaction).

> let’s make the states highlighted visually in some way when they are hovered with a mouse.

All this can be done without issue together with the popup opened on click.

Comment: Thanks! Well, have to see how install a plugin etc.... Even if the coding is easier there are other obstacles for me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To get a mouse-over popup, in HTML one would simply add an attribute `title`, for example to an `IMG` element. For a Leaflet marker, it is just as easy: a `title` property can be added to its properties. Example:

```
return L.marker(latlng, {icon: new icol({iconUrl: icon.png}), title: feature.properties.name});
```

Here, we simply display the name of a feature. This way, it is also possible to see just a short name or number when hovering, but a more complete information when clicking with the mouse. No need to explain the second one: it's in the question.